# Is there a Pythonic way to get the key associated with a failed dict or pandas row assignment?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data pipeline where we processing data as a pandas DataFrame. We need to do a bunch of operations on each row where some operations on one column depend on the values in other columns, so we use pandas `apply`, similar to:

```
def check_row(row):
    if row['C'] == 'foo':
        row['B'] += row['A']
        
    row['C'] = row['C'].zfill(5)
    
    #etc
    
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 'foo'), 
                   (4, 5, 'bar'), 
                   (7,8,'baz')], 
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df.apply(check_row, axis=1)
```

Sometimes, the data that comes into this pipeline does not satisfy our assumptions, and exceptions are generate (e.g. non-string value in column C). I would like to catch these exceptions and flag these rows.

Currently we wrap the entire check_row function in a try-except block and note those rows as problems (there are many such assignments). However, we lose track of which actual assignment failed. Is there a more pythonic way to catch the specific assignment, other than wrapping each in its own try-except? This feels ugly:

```
def check_row(row):
    try:
        if row['C'] == 'foo':
            row['B'] += row['A']
    except Exception as e:
        row['errors'] = f"Failed to assign to B: {repr(e)}"

    try:
       row['C'] = row['C'].zfill(5)
    except Exception as e:
        row['errors'] = f"Failed to assign to C: {repr(e)}"
    
    #etc
    
    return row
```

I thought about something like:

```
def assign(column, value):
    """inside the scope of check_row"""
    try:
        row[column] = value
    except Exception as e:
        row['errors'] = f"Failed to assign to {column}: {repr(e)}"
```

But of course its the calculation of value that's failing, not the actual assignment, so this doesn't quite do it. Any ideas?

Comment: create an abstraction to help you avoid repeating code and write a clear program. A function is one of the standard abstractions we often reach for, but in this case a context manager would be even better I think. And please always specify an exception on your `except`s.

Comment: Thanks @creanion. It's not clear to me how a context manager can help here, can you give an example?

In practice we catch and log the details of the error. I'll edit my code to make that clearer. We want to avoid falling down on any exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with dicts exactly? As far as I know, assignments to a dict can't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't actually need the key itself, just some way to determine which part failed. And it's not necessarily the assignment that's failing either. So how about using the traceback?

Exception objects contain a reference to their traceback, so if you keep them around, you can refer back to it later. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(1, 2, 'foo'),
     (4, 5, 'bar'),
     (7, 8, 'baz'),
     (3, 9, 10500)],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

errors = []

def wrap_check_row(row):
    try:
        return check_row(row)
    except Exception as e:
        errors.append((row, e))

df.apply(wrap_check_row, axis=1)
```

```
     A    B      C
0  1.0  3.0  00foo
1  4.0  5.0  00bar
2  7.0  8.0  00baz
3  NaN  NaN   None
```

Then afterwards, we can see which rows failed and the relevant exception:

```
import sys
import traceback

for row, exc in errors:
    print('Failed index:', row.name, file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exception(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
```

```
Failed index: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-bc47ffa7c200>", line 6, in wrap_check_row
    return check_row(row)
  File "<ipython-input-3-ceb5d79bdcf5>", line 5, in check_row
    row['C'] = row['C'].zfill(5)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'zfill'
```

**Sidenote**: In Python 3.10, it looks like you can simplify the [`print_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception) call to `traceback.print_exception(exc)`.

Comment: I think that the fact that the traceback provides the line number is sufficient here, and we capture the row index. Thanks!